# How to use Cognito LOGOUT endpoint to really log out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0

I'm trying to use Federated Authentication to enable login with Microsoft AD. It works fine and we can login. But when I call LOGOUT endpoint as the documentation says ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html ) and try to login again I'm not being redirected to Microsoft page to type my email and password again.

It seems like the email and password I typed are in cache and I just can see this login page again if I clean cache. How can we really logout the user in a way that when he login he needs to type his email and password again ?

**Edit: I enabled 'Sing Out Idp Flow' as suggested in the answer but now I'm getting a 400 response saying "Required String parameter client_id is not present"**

**Does anybody have any clue how to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure you select 'Enable IdP sign out flow' on your SAML Identity provider in Cognito. After navigating your browser to the logout endpoint, you should then be redirected to the SAML IDP logout aswell.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-console.html

> Select Enable IdP sign out flow if you want your user to be logged out
>   from the SAML IdP when logging out from Amazon Cognito.
>
> Enabling this flow sends a signed logout request to the SAML IdP when
>   the LOGOUT Endpoint is called.
>
> Configure this endpoint for consuming logout responses from your IdP.
>   This endpoint uses post binding.

Comment: Hello, really thanks for your help! I as unaware about this documentation. I enabled and they go to logout flow but it is not working properly yet. It always return me a bad request saying  " Required String parameter client_id  is not present " even using hosted UI or calling API directly. Do you have any clues what can be ? I'm sending client id

Comment: Solved! I wrongly set the Cognito URL again in logoff URL in Microsoft AD but I shouldn't set this. THANK YOU!! :D

Comment: Hi @ThauanyMoedano, Can you share whats the API you called to logout? I tried as below: https://domaincognito.com/logout?response_type=code&client_id=3840932849328t&logout_uri=https://mywebsite.com/saml2/logout&redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com&state=STATE&scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin

Comment: Hello! It is quite some time I did this project and I don't have the APIs anymore. But according to the documentation, the logout API should be something like this https://<your Amazon Cognito domain>/saml2/logout  ... Maybe you are missing the /saml2 in the URL

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I enabled 'Sing Out Idp Flow' as suggested in the answer but now I'm getting a 400 response saying "Required String parameter client_id is not present" Does anybody have any clue how to solve this problem ?

You need to include the client_id parameter when calling the logout endpoint, the parameter is specified as required in the documentation you provided. The client id can be found in AWS Cognito console in User pools > Your User pool name > App Integration > Your app client name and you should see a Client ID there.